# calculate sum of field based on Boolean expression in rdlc Reort

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I'm trying to calculate the total of `cost` in `RDLC report` using `expressions`

I applied the following and it works fine :

```
=SUM(Val(Fields!PCOST.Value))
```

But I tried to apply another `expression` to calculate the cost but with a condition like below :

```
=IIf(Fields!Active.Value =False, SUM(Val(Fields!PCOST.Value)),0)
```

but only I got `0.00`?

can anyone explain why?

**the table [Active] field type is bit**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to `sum` the result of the `IIF` rather than the other way round. I've not tested this but I think the following should work...

```
=SUM(IIf(Fields!Active.Value =False, Val(Fields!PCOST.Value),0))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Alan, in fact after I reviewing my code I note that issue and fixed it, anyway I was sent an email to stackoverflow.com to delete this question before I receive any replay, but I'm surprised now how this question still.


I hope that  stackoverflow.com to add a deletion query button with a justification box to remove the question and  to avoid any embarrassing situation like this